# Algorithm for fitting 2D polygons in an area?

Tags: algorithm, polygon, area

Is there a standard for this? Algorithm name?

Say:
I have 10 polygons of different sizes.
I have an area of specific size.

I want to know how to fill the most polygons in that area, and how they are fitted.

Note:
Polygons may be rotated depending on the restriction set.

Comment: You can try your luck at http://mathoverflow.net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible name is a [Packing Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem). It is related to the [Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). These problems tend to be NP-hard, and many require heuristics. If you can constrain the allowed forms of polygons and of the area, there may exist a more efficient algorithm for your special case.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at "Dancing Links" in Wikipedia for Donald Knuth's solution to the exact cover problem - which includes tiling - your question can be looked at as a tiling problem

Answer (score 1):

IF (that's a big if) all your polygons were rectangles, and the area into which they are to fit is also a rectangle, then this would be called bin-packing, Google will overwhelm you with information about this.  If they're not then I guess that you are looking for a variant of bin-packing, and I guess some more that you are into an NP problem for which 'try and test' is about the best algorithm around.